# Why is the search form not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I use a live search form [working version](https://osvaldas.info/real-time-search-in-javascript),
but why is mine not working how it should work? 
I geuss it is because the div class="wrapper faq" is messing things up?

Sorry for the slobby html, but copying 1500 lines and 4 css docs wasnt going to help.

thanks in advance!

```js
<script>

 'use strict';


 // search & highlight

 ;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
 {
  var $container = $( '.faq' );
  if( !$container.length ) return true;

  var $input   = $container.find( 'input' ),
   $notfound  = $container.find( '.faq__notfound' ),
   $items   = $container.find( '> ul > li' ),
   $item   = $(),
   itemsIndexed = [];

  $items.each( function()
  {
   itemsIndexed.push( $( this ).text().replace( /\s{2,}/g, ' ' ).toLowerCase() );
  });

  $input.on( 'keyup', function( e )
  {
   if( e.keyCode == 13 ) // enter
   {
    $input.trigger( 'blur' );
    return true;
   }

   $items.each( function()
   {
    $item = $( this );
    $item.html( $item.html().replace( /<span class="highlight">([^<]+)<\/span>/gi, '$1' ) );
   });

   var searchVal = $.trim( $input.val() ).toLowerCase();
   if( searchVal.length )
   {
    for( var i in itemsIndexed )
    {
     $item = $items.eq( i );
     if( itemsIndexed[ i ].indexOf( searchVal ) != -1 )
      $item.removeClass( 'is-hidden' ).html( $item.html().replace( new RegExp( searchVal+'(?!([^<]+)?>)', 'gi' ), '<span class="highlight">$&</span>' ) );
     else
      $item.addClass( 'is-hidden' );
    }
   }
   else $items.removeClass( 'is-hidden' );

   $notfound.toggleClass( 'is-visible', $items.not( '.is-hidden' ).length == 0 );
  });
 })( jQuery, window, document );


 // toggling items on title press

 ;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
 {
  $( document ).on( 'click', '.faq h2 a', function( e )
  {
   e.preventDefault();
   $( this ).parents( 'li' ).toggleClass( 'is-active' );
  });
 })( jQuery, window, document );


 // auto-show item content when show results reduces to single

 ;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
 {
  var $container = $( '.faq' );
  if( !$container.length ) return true;

  var $input  = $container.find( 'input' ),
   $items  = $container.find( '> ul > li' ),
   $item  = $();

  $input.on( 'keyup', function()
  {
   $item = $items.not( '.is-hidden' );
   if( $item.length == 1 )
    $item.addClass( 'js--autoshown is-active' );
   else
    $items.filter( '.js--autoshown' ).removeClass( 'js--autoshown is-active' );
  });
 })( jQuery, window, document );

</script>
```

```html
 <!-- Search bar -->
        <div class="search-wrapper faq" >
            <div class="container container--add faq">

                    <input type="search" value="" placeholder="Search">
                
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- Movie preview item -->
        
            <div id="Page1" class="page" style="">
            <ul>
             <li id="faq-1">
             <h2><a href="#faq-1" class="movie__title link--huge">Last Vegas (2013)</a></h2>
                <div class="movie movie--preview movie--full release">
                     <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                            <div class="movie__images">
                                <img alt='' src="images/movie/movie-sample1.jpg">
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 movie__about">
                            

                                                    
                                </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>                                       

                </div>
                </li>
                <!-- end movie preview item -->

                <!-- Movie preview item -->
                <li id="faq-2">
             <h2><a href="#faq-2" class="movie__title link--huge">the book thief (2013)</a></h2>
                <div class="movie movie--preview movie--full comments">
                     <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                            <div class="movie__images">
                                <img alt='' src="images/movie/movie-sample2.jpg">
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 movie__about">
                           

                            
                                
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
                <!-- end movie preview item -->
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are closing off the .faq div  in the HTML too soon - move the  from before the  to the end in order to wrap the contents into into the parent .faq div. Also - you have some closing  issues in the ul as well- i have rejigged it a bit - insert the following code into your - replacing the entire section with mine to see if this helps. This is an example of when text indentation and checking the openings / closings is useful.

```
 <!-- Search bar -->
    <div class="search-wrapper faq" >
       <div class="container container--add faq">
            <input type="search" value="" placeholder="Search">
       </div>

      <!-- Movie preview item -->
      <div id="Page1" class="page" style="">
         <ul>
            <li id="faq-1">
              <h2><a href="#faq-1" class="movie__title link--huge">Last Vegas (2013)</a></h2>
              <div class="movie movie--preview movie--full release clearfix">
                   <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                       <div class="movie__images">
                          <img alt='' src="images/movie/movie-sample1.jpg">
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 movie__about">
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li><!-- end movie preview item -->
            <li id="faq-2"><!-- Movie preview item -->
                <h2><a href="#faq-2" class="movie__title link--huge">the book thief (2013)</a></h2>
                <div class="movie movie--preview movie--full comments clearfix">
                     <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <div class="movie__images">
                            <img alt='' src="images/movie/movie-sample2.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10 movie__about">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- end movie preview item -->
      </div><!--end of page 1 div-->
    </div><!--end of faq-->
```